# Angular routing not passing in component or views

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

Moved into Angular 2 and used the fountain web app library to get started. Had things working fine, then had to move my code to a sub directory for the sake of the rest of our app. Thought I would just need to revise my pathing for routing in the route.js, but still not getting past the index and showing any views. Not sure why.

My file structure is this:
[image]

My routes.js is:

```
var ng = require('@angular/core');

var HelloComponent = require('./hello');

exports.STATES = [{
    name: 'App',
    url: '/',
    component: HelloComponent
}];

exports.MyUIRouterConfig = ng.Class({
    constructor: function() {},

    configure: function(uiRouter) {
        uiRouter.urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function() {
            return uiRouter.stateService.go('App');
        });
    }
});
```

And my index.js is:

```
var ng = require('@angular/core');
var ngPlatformBrowser = require('@angular/platform-browser');
var uiRouter = require('ui-router-ng2');
var myRoutes = require('./routes');

import 'bootstrap';

var HelloComponent = require('./hello');

module.exports = uiRouter.UIRouterModule({
    imports: [
        ngPlatformBrowser.BrowserModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        HelloComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        uiRouter.provideUIRouter({ configClass: myRoutes.MyUIRouterConfig })
    ],
    states: myRoutes.STATES,
    bootstrap: [uiRouter.UIView]
})(
    ng.Class({
        constructor: function() {}
    })
);
```

With the view for index here and all I get is the "loading...." and it doesn't move on and show the injected hello component:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Volutus Management Portal</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://fountainjs.io/assets/imgs/fountain.png" />
</head>

<body>
    <ui-view>Loading...</ui-view>
</body>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong here? What can I do to fix this please?

Comment: Check if the import paths are correct, both in your components and in the app.module

Comment: The component it should be trying to load is at the same level. So not sure why this will not load.